# how can i use variable table $r1 in the query $r2 instead of table name on FROM clause in php file

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

```
$r1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT course_id,status FROM attendance WHERE stud_id = '$stud_id'");

$r2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT course_name,status FROM **$r1** NATURAL JOIN course WHERE stud_id = '$stud_id'");
```

Comment: i would suggest you create a variable for table name and use it instead.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use [subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subqueries.html) for this.

```
$r2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT course_name,status FROM 
        (SELECT course_id,status FROM attendance WHERE stud_id = '$stud_id') 
        NATURAL JOIN course WHERE stud_id = '$stud_id'");
```

Comment: That's fine but i wants use of $r1 as i given in query $r2.I want to know that it is possible or not because i am using 3-4 queries of that type.So the resulted query from using subqueries as you provide is a very complex and bigger aslo. And tracking of that big query next time is very tedious.

Comment: according to by mind, you have to use subquery.you cannot select from dataset (in your case $r1) with mysql query. You have to use subquery. And my bad. you have to make aliases right and use them correctly in joining. I just wanted you to know that you have to use subquery for that

Comment: And this query returns a error on the subquery **SELECT** as This type of clause was previously parsed on xampp directly

Answer (score 0):

First of all, never use variables without proper escaping ([mysqli::real-escape-string](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php))

And you can just join two tables like that:

```
$r2 = mysqli_query(
    $con,
    "SELECT c.course_name, a.status FROM attendance a
    INNER JOIN course c ON c.stud_id = a.stud_id 
    WHERE stud_id = '$stud_id'"
);
```